# Equivalent of "left" and "right" SQL string manipulation functions in Querydsl?

Tags: querydsl

I have a SQL statement similar to this:

```
select left(right(my_string_column, 10), 5)
from my_table;
```

Works fine, it first takes the right-most 10 characters of `my_string_column`, and from that, gives me the first five characters of those ten characters. I'm trying to find an equivalent of this in [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/), something like:

```
myTable.myStringColumn.right(10).left(5)
```

But there are no "left" and "right" methods. How would I write this in Querydsl instead?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the substring function.  Here is an example I got to work locally with querydsl v3.2.3:

```
QMyTable g = new QMyTable("g");
query = new SQLQuery(connection , dialect);
List<Tuple> l = query.from(g).list(g.mystringfield,
        g.mystringfield.substring(g.mystringfield.length().subtract(10),
        g.mystringfield.length() ).substring(0, 5).as("mystringfield5"));
for (Tuple t : l) {
    System.out.println(t.get(g.mystringfield) + " =====> " + t.get(1, String.class));
}
```

The generated query would look similar to this:

```
select g.mystringfield,
(substr(substr(g.mystringfield,(length(g.mystringfield) - ?)+1,length(g.mystringfield)-(length(g.mystringfield) - ?)),1,5)) as mystringfield5
from MyTable g
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had problems getting part of your solution to work (https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/520) but Timo wasn't able to replicate, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

left/right support is not yet implemented in Querydsl. You can emulate left easily with substring(0, size), but right is more tricky and I suggest to create a ticket for it.